# how to use workbox cache back4app data?

Tags: parsing, workbox, back4app

I am updating my website to PWA, and I am using google workbox as service worker to cache data. I can cache JS, images css etc, but I can't cache back4app query data.

I tried to use `workbox.backgroundSync`, but when I check in `IndexDB`, it cache nothing. Here is my code:

```
const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', 
{
     maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      'https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/*',
      workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
      plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
   }),
   'POST'
);
```

1) Is it possible to cache back4app data using `workbox`?

2) If possible, how do I do it? Can you give me an example of the code? I have tried for two days but didn't succeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a npm module called "workbox-build" and it can be installed at the cloud code. If you install it and follow its guides, it will probably work as expected. :)